# Dynamically add elements to view based on xml parsed in viewmodel

Tags: c#, mvvm, windows-store-apps

Hallo and thank you for your time.

I am making a project for school, and ive run into a problem that id like to solve over the weekend. (my teacher is obviously not available for questions)

I am using the MVVM architechture for my app.
I wish to dynamically add stackpanels(with some content) to the View, based on how many entries for the selected category that i find in the associated XML file in the ViewModel

I have created a XMLContainer class, which uses the singleton pattern.
I have an enum called 'Categories' with the available categories.
I have a ViewModel called 'SecondPageViewModel'

I have only been doing this for 2 months, so even if you think its obvious what you mean. Elaborate a bit more please :)

My tools:
Visual Studio Ultimate 2013
Resharper 8

Categories enum:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace TouristAppV3.Enums
{
    enum Categories
    {
        Bars,
        Festivals,
        Hotels,
        Museums,
        Restaurants,
    }

}
```

XMLContainer class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using Windows.ApplicationModel;
using Windows.Media.MediaProperties;
using Windows.Storage;
using TouristAppV3.Enums;

namespace TouristAppV3.Classes
{
    /// <summary>
    /// This class uses the singleton pattern.
    /// Use GetInstance() to use the class
    /// </summary>
    class XMLContainer
    {
        private static XMLContainer _object;
        private IEnumerable<XElement> BarsXML;
        private IEnumerable<XElement> HotelsXML;
        private IEnumerable<XElement> MuseumsXML;
        private IEnumerable<XElement> RestaurantsXML;
        private IEnumerable<XElement> FestivalsXML;

        private XMLContainer()
        {
            GetBars();
            GetFestivals();
            GetHotels();
            GetMuseums();
            GetRestaurants();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Usage: XMLContainer "desired name" = XMLContainer.GetInstance()
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>The same object every time.</returns>
        public static XMLContainer GetInstance()
        {
            if (_object == null)
            {
                _object = new XMLContainer();
            }
            return _object;
        }


        /// <summary>
        /// Returns the XML for the requested category
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="desiredCategory">The desired category</param>
        /// <returns>ienumerable xelement</returns>
        public IEnumerable<XElement> ReturnXMLFrom(Categories desiredCategory)
        {
            switch (desiredCategory)
            {
                case Categories.Bars:
                    return BarsXML;
                case Categories.Hotels:
                    return HotelsXML;
                case Categories.Festivals:
                    return FestivalsXML;
                case Categories.Museums:
                    return MuseumsXML;
                case Categories.Restaurants:
                    return RestaurantsXML;
            }
            return null;
        }

        private void GetBars()
        {
            GetXML(Categories.Bars);
        }

        private void GetHotels()
        {
            GetXML(Categories.Hotels);
        }

        private void GetMuseums()
        {
            GetXML(Categories.Museums);
        }

        private void GetRestaurants()
        {
            GetXML(Categories.Restaurants);
        }

        private void GetFestivals()
        {
            GetXML(Categories.Festivals);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets the content of the xml file associated with the selected category
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="selectedCategory"></param>
        private async void GetXML(Categories selectedCategory)
        {
            string _selectedCategory = selectedCategory.ToString();
            StorageFile categoryFile = null;

            StorageFolder installationFolder = Package.Current.InstalledLocation;
            string xmlPath = @"Assets\xml\Models\" + _selectedCategory + ".xml";
            categoryFile = await installationFolder.GetFileAsync(xmlPath);

            Stream categoryStream = await categoryFile.OpenStreamForReadAsync();
            XDocument categoryXDocument = XDocument.Load(categoryStream);
            categoryStream.Dispose();
            IEnumerable<XElement> returnThis = categoryXDocument.Descendants(_selectedCategory.Remove(_selectedCategory.Count() - 1).ToLower());
            switch (_selectedCategory)
            {
                case "Bars":
                    BarsXML = returnThis;
                    break;
                case "Hotels":
                    HotelsXML = returnThis;
                    break;
                case "Restaurants":
                    RestaurantsXML = returnThis;
                    break;
                case "Museums":
                    MuseumsXML = returnThis;
                    break;
                case "Festivals":
                    FestivalsXML = returnThis;
                    break;
            }

        }

    }
}
```

SecondPageViewModel:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Collections.Specialized;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using Windows.ApplicationModel;
using Windows.Storage;
using Windows.UI.Core;
using TouristAppV3.Annotations;
using TouristAppV3.Classes;
using TouristAppV3.Enums;

namespace TouristAppV3.ViewModel
{
    class SecondPageViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private IEnumerable<XElement> xml;
        private string _selectedCategory = MainPageViewModel.SelectedCategory;


        public SecondPageViewModel()
        {
            LoadXML();
        }

        private void LoadXML()
        {
            XMLContainer xmlContainer = XMLContainer.GetInstance();
            switch (_selectedCategory)
            {
                case "Bars":
                    xml = xmlContainer.ReturnXMLFrom(Categories.Bars);
                    break;
                case "Hotels":
                    xml = xmlContainer.ReturnXMLFrom(Categories.Hotels);
                    break;
                case "Restaurants":
                    xml = xmlContainer.ReturnXMLFrom(Categories.Restaurants);
                    break;
                case "Museums":
                    xml = xmlContainer.ReturnXMLFrom(Categories.Museums);
                    break;
                case "Festivals":
                    xml = xmlContainer.ReturnXMLFrom(Categories.Festivals);
                    break;
            }

        }


        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        [NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator]
        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
            if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

Again, thank you for your time

Comment: Deserialize the XML into POCOs, these are your models.  Store them in properties on your VM.  Bind your UI to these, using DataTemplates to show UI corresponding to each type.  And now you're done.

Comment: I fixed the problem with databinding to a GridView element. Id like to post my code for others to read. But ive got no option to add an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem using a GridView.
For more details on the GridView element, read here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh780650.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

This is my implementation of the solution i came up with.

Finished SecondPageViewModel:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Collections.Specialized;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using Windows.ApplicationModel;
using Windows.Storage;
using Windows.UI.Core;
using TouristAppV3.Annotations;
using TouristAppV3.Classes;
using TouristAppV3.Enums;
using TouristAppV3.Model;

namespace TouristAppV3.ViewModel
{
    class SecondPageViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        #region Fields
        private IEnumerable<XElement> xml;
        private string _selectedCategory = MainPageViewModel.SelectedCategory;
        private string _xmlElementOfInterrest = "type";
        private ObservableCollection<GenericModel> _places;

        #endregion

        #region Constructor
        public SecondPageViewModel()
        {
            LoadXML();
            Places = new ObservableCollection<GenericModel>();
            PopulatePlaces();
        }


        #endregion

        #region Methods
        /// <summary>
        /// Loads xml for _selectedCategory
        /// </summary>
        private void LoadXML()
        {
            XMLContainer xmlContainer = XMLContainer.GetInstance();
            switch (_selectedCategory)
            {
                case "Bars":
                    xml = xmlContainer.ReturnXMLFrom(Categories.Bars);
                    break;
                case "Hotels":
                    xml = xmlContainer.ReturnXMLFrom(Categories.Hotels);
                    break;
                case "Restaurants":
                    xml = xmlContainer.ReturnXMLFrom(Categories.Restaurants);
                    break;
                case "Museums":
                    xml = xmlContainer.ReturnXMLFrom(Categories.Museums);
                    break;
                case "Festivals":
                    xml = xmlContainer.ReturnXMLFrom(Categories.Festivals);
                    break;
            }

        }

        private void PopulatePlaces()
        {
            if (_selectedCategory == Categories.Bars.ToString() ||
                _selectedCategory == Categories.Hotels.ToString() ||
                _selectedCategory == Categories.Museums.ToString() ||
                _selectedCategory == Categories.Restaurants.ToString())
            {
                if (_selectedCategory == Categories.Hotels.ToString())
                {
                    _xmlElementOfInterrest = "quality";
                }
                if (_selectedCategory == Categories.Museums.ToString())
                {
                    _xmlElementOfInterrest = "subtitle";
                }
            }
            try
            {
                foreach (XElement place in xml)
                {
                    string name = place.Attribute("name").Value;
                    string subtitle = place.Element(_xmlElementOfInterrest).Value;
                    string imagePath = place.Element("imageURL").Value;
                    Places.Add(new GenericModel(name, subtitle, _selectedCategory, imagePath));
                }
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
            }
        }

        #endregion

        #region Properties

        public string PageName
        {
            get { return _selectedCategory; }
            private set { _selectedCategory = value; }
        }

        public ObservableCollection<GenericModel> Places
        {
            get { return _places; }
            set { _places = value; }
        }

        #endregion

        #region OnPropertyChanged method
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        [NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator]
        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
            if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
        #endregion
    }
}
```

The GridView part of the View:

```
<GridView x:Name="gridview_items"
            Grid.Row="1"
            ItemsSource="{Binding Places, Mode=TwoWay}"
            IsItemClickEnabled="True"
            ItemClick="ItemView_ItemClick">
    <GridView.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <WrapGrid Orientation="Horizontal" MaximumRowsOrColumns="4"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </GridView.ItemsPanel>
    <GridView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="331" Height="200">
                <Border Background="{ThemeResource ListViewItemPlaceholderBackgroundThemeBrush}">
                    <Image Source="{Binding ImagePath}" Stretch="UniformToFill" AutomationProperties.Name="{Binding Name}"/>
                </Border>
                <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Background="{ThemeResource ListViewItemOverlayBackgroundThemeBrush}">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" Foreground="{ThemeResource ListViewItemOverlayForegroundThemeBrush}" Style="{StaticResource TitleTextBlockStyle}" Height="60"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Subtitle}" Foreground="{ThemeResource ListViewItemOverlaySecondaryForegroundThemeBrush}" Style="{StaticResource CaptionTextBlockStyle}" TextWrapping="NoWrap"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </GridView.ItemTemplate>
</GridView>
```

At the first opening tag of the Grid element containing this GridView, i set the DataContext, like so.

```
<Grid.DataContext>
    <ViewModel:SecondPageViewModel/>
</Grid.DataContext>
```

This achieved the effect i wanted, but in a much cleaner way than i was originally thinking.

I hope this explenation is clear to others. If not, feel free to ask me questions. And i will elaborate as much as i can.